# Angular 2/4 entire html page loading into child component

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-ui-router

I have a component called UserDash, that uses the

```
templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
```

My problem is that the whole html page is somehow being loaded in again, instead of the template

There are no errors.
I've attached an image for clarity

[image]

Really not sure where to start, was working fine yesterday

Comment: Since you mentioned it was working fine yesterday, do check your network calls. One of them might be throwing whole HTML page as response.

Comment: Yes you are right the template is responding with the entire page, must be why no errors, but not sure how to fix this

Comment: `template is responding with the entire page` Do you mean network call? if yes, then you need to handle that call better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, not sure how I can handle call better, I'm loading in a templateUrl to a component, the actual response from the template.html is the repeated HTML page ,shouldn't it just use the template? if I use inline it works

Comment: I am assuming that the backend guy might be throwing the whole page when you provide wrong url or data as request.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that

Comment: Roy, let me know if my assumption is right. Thanks.

Comment: Afraid not, none of that is being handled on the server at the moment, just checked, even the css returns html